# Control Panel : put content edit entries from one channel in a link

Tags: control-panel

Think this might be an easy question but never found the solution.

I want my clients to have a quick link per channel for what they otherwise have to find via *Content > Edit > Channels*. 
If i save the url it redirects to the *Content > Edit* without the filter

it would be much more user friendly for clients to have a link with "blogposts", "contacts", "events" on the right sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but the links are tied specifically to the user.
So, you can login, as the user and build their list of quick links.
You can force this by browsing to the users profile in the CP as a Super Admin and it will give you a menu pick to login as that user.  You don't need to know their password.

You can also do the same with the buttons in the top menu.
Browse to the entry listings for the channel you want, then select the "Add" link and it will add it to the header.
Again, these are user specific, so you would need to be logged in as the user.

I'm not sure, but I don't think you can makes those global without some code re-working.

Answer (score 1):

Three choices:

- [CP Menu Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-menu-master)
- [BN Edit Menu](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bn-edit-menu)
- [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/flexible-admin)